# How I delete data from 'Realm Database' on button click?

Tags: android, realm

How can I delete specific data from `realm` on button click event?

I have an `RecyclerView` and in it I set `CardView` where my `EditText` and delete button is set. I want that when I press delete button on `CardView` the data is deleted from `CardView` and also from `realm` database. I try more effort but I could not get success.

**Activity Screen:**

[image: Activity Screen]

Comment: I hope it'll help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952200

Answer (score 1):

Use `deleteFromRealm()` to delete specific record

```
  val realm: Realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            try {
                realm.executeTransaction {
                    val info = realm.where<CLASS>() // replace your realm class file
                            .equalTo(KEY, VALUE)  // match data with key - value pair
                            .findFirst()
                    info?.deleteFromRealm() // delete from realm
                }
            } finally {
                realm.close()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `rows.clear();` for more information visit here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36736415/9315408

Answer (score 0):

In 0.88.3, version of Realm, use `clear()`

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
  @Override
  public void execute(Realm realm) {
      RealmResults<User> rows = realm.where(User.class).equalTo(User.USER_ID,userId).findAll();
      rows.clear();
  }
});
```

From 0.89 version of Realm, use `deleteAllFromRealm()` instead.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
  @Override
  public void execute(Realm realm) {
      RealmResults<User> result = realm.where(User.class).equalTo(User.USER_ID,userId).findAll();
      result.deleteAllFromRealm();
  }
});
```